# Getting boolean from true_type/false_type typedef from dependent class in enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I have a class

```
template <typename T>
struct Trait { typedef std::false_type IsGood; };

template <>
struct Trait<int> { typedef std::true_type IsGood; };
```

A call like this fails to compile on MSVC 2010

```
template <typename T, typename Enable = void> class Foo;

template <typename T>
class Foo <T, std::enable_if<typename Trait<T>::IsGood::value>::type>
{};

// This fails as well
template <typename T>
class Foo <T, typename std::enable_if<Trait<T>::IsGood::value>::type>
{};

// And this fails horribly
template <typename T>
class Foo <T, typename std::enable_if<typename Trait<T>::IsGood::value>::type>
{};
```

while

```
template <typename T>
class Foo <T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::true_type, 
    typename Trait<T>::IsGood>::value>::type>
{};
```

works -- why?

The error message is:

```
main.cpp(12): error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'std::tr1::enable_if<_Test>'
          with
          [
              _Test=false
          ]
main.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'type'
main.cpp(12): error C2065: 'type' : undeclared identifier
main.cpp(13): error C2976: 'Foo' : too few template arguments
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `typename` at wrong place. This is correct:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo <T, typename std::enable_if<Trait<T>::IsGood::value>::type>
{};        // ^^^^^^^ here should be typename
```

Now it compiles fine: http://ideone.com/0SwO9

But you're using `typename` as:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo <T, std::enable_if<typename  Trait<T>::IsGood::value>::type>
{};                        //^^^^^^^ wrong place
```

`Trait<T>::IsGood::value` is not a *type*, So you cannot apply `typename` on it.

GCC error message is very much clear:

> prog.cpp:12:62: error: **type/value mismatch** at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<bool <anonymous>, class _Tp> struct std::enable_if'

See yourself : http://ideone.com/9ujJv

Comment: Doesn't compile using MSVC2010. Compiler bug?

Comment: And here we go: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693591/std-enable-if-fails-to-compile-works-with-gcc

Comment: @Anteru: You better mention this topic link as well on microsoft connect.